# Actualizar registro sin que interfieran relaciones

Tags: php, sql, html5, update

Intento actualizar un registro  de la tabla tblusuario
que esta relacionada con la tabla tblmunicipio
El problema es que para poder actualizar el registro me exige que debo actualizar el municipio, si no lo hago y actualizo otro campo diferente no me lo permite,pero si actualizo el municipio juntamente con otros campos si me deja actualizar, basicamente para poder actualizar algun registro debo actualizar el municipio obligatoriamente.
Intenté hacer el update sql con inner join , pero no tuve el conocimieno suficiente y no lo conseguí.

Aqui esta mi formulario

`````
     <form action="update.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label " >Documento de identidad:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="documento"  class="form-control col-8 rounded " value="<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Nombres:</label><br><br>
                        <input type="text" name="nombres" class="form-control col-8 rounded " value="<?php echo $datos['nombres'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Apellidos:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control col-8 rounded" value="<?php echo $datos['apellidos'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label " >Correo :</label><br>
                        <input type="email" name="correo"  id="correo" class="form-control col-8 rounded" value="<?php echo $datos['correo'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label " >Telefono:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control col-8 rounded " value="<?php echo $datos['telefono'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label " >Direccion:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control col-8 rounded " value="<?php echo $datos['direccion'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label " >Clave:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="clave" class="form-control col-8 rounded " value="<?php echo $datos['clave'] ?>"><br><br>
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label " for="depatamento"> Departamento: </label><br>
                                    <select Class="form-control col-8 rounded" name="depatamento" id="tbl_departamento"  class="col-8">
                                        <option value="" disabled> - Seleccione - </option>
                                        <?php foreach ($filas as $op): //llenar las opciones del primer select ?>
                                                                                                                                                            <option value="<?=$op['codigo']?>"> <?=$op['nombre']?> </option>
                                                                                                                                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label" for="municipio">Municipio: </label><br>
                                    <select Class="form-control col-8 rounded" name="municipio" id="tbl_municipio"  disabled="" class="col-8">
                                        <option value="<?php echo $datos['municipio'] ?>"><?php echo $datos['municipio'] ?></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
````
Este es el archivo update.php a donde redirecciona el formulario
````
<?php 
include ("../includes/conexion.php");

$documento = $_POST["documento"];
$nombres = $_POST["nombres"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$clave = $_POST["clave"];
$municipio = $_POST["municipio"];


$up = $conexion -> query("UPDATE tblusuario 
SET documento='$documento', nombres='$nombres',apellidos='$apellidos',
correo='$correo',telefono='$telefono',
direccion='$direccion',clave='$clave',municipio='$municipio'
 WHERE documento='$documento' ");   


if ($up) {

    echo "si";
}
else{


    echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";
}

 ?>
````
Si intento actualizar otro input sin actualizar el input municipio, me sale este error:
````
Notice: Undefined index: municipio in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_usuario\update.php on line 11
````
Pero cuando actualizo el municipio y otros inputs a la misma vez si se me permite hacer el cambio.
`````

Comment: Agrega tu formulario por favor

Comment: Si quitas _municipio_ del formulario, también debes quitarlo de la consulta.

Comment: Hola. Si tu proyecto no está aún en producción, estás a tiempo de **corregir tu modelo de datos**: municipio no es atributo de ninguna persona o usuario, más aún, no es atributo necesario para caracterizar un usuario; en consecuencia no debe estar en la tabla de usuarios, ¿Qué pasaría si por alguna condición futura, todavía no prevista, un usuario pueda entrar en relación con varios municipios? Debes crear una tabla de relación relUsuariosMunicipios dónde sólo haya un id de relación y los índices de usuario y municipio. Eso hará tu modelo versátil y le dará futuro.

Comment: Como principio general, todo atributo no esencial, que vaya a ser atribuido relacionalmente, debe estar fuera de las tablas a las que se vinculará y ser situado en una tabla para su tipo o naturaleza. Y, debe ser asignado en tablas de relación.

Comment: Leyendo nuevamente la pregunta, parece que el problema es que no sabes cómo llenar el _select_ con los municipios disponibles, de ser así, solo necesitas hacer una consulta para leerlos y crear las opciones dentro de un ciclo, igual a como haces con _departamento_

Comment: El select si se llena, lo que pasa es que no puse ese codigo porque no me parecio relevante, el problema no esta en llenar el select si no en actualizar el dato